# R Shiny - Using JQuery selectors in shinyjs::toggleState to disable dynamically created buttons

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, shinyjs

The app below contains a module that inserts a UI object each time the `Add` button is clicked. The object consists of a `selectInput` and a `Remove` button, which removes the UI object:

[image]

I would like to disable the `Remove` button if there is only one `selectInput` left in the DOM.

To do this, I keep track of 1) how many inputs were inserted using a counter `rv$ct` and 2) how many were removed inside `rv$rmvd`. I set up an observer that listens to the value of the difference between `rv$ct` and `length(rv$rmvd)` and use `shinyjs::toggleState` inside that observer to enable the `Remove` button if the difference is greater than 1.

The app is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# module UI ---------------------------------------------------------------

modUI <- function(id) {
  
  ns = NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns('add'), 'Add'),
    fluidRow(div(id = ns('placeholder')))
  )
  
}

# module server -----------------------------------------------------------

modServer <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ns = session$ns
  
  rv = reactiveValues(ct = 0, rmvd = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    
    rv$ct = rv$ct + 1
    
    Id = function(id) paste0(id, rv$ct)
    
    insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#', ns('placeholder')),
      ui = div(
        id = Id(ns('inputGroup')),
        splitLayout(
          cellWidths = '10%',
          h4(Id('State ')),
          selectInput(Id(ns('state')), 'State:', state.abb),
          div(
            class = 'rmvBttn',
            actionButton(Id(ns('remove')), 'Remove'))
        )
        
      )
    )
    
    remove_id = Id('remove')
    remove_group = Id(ns('inputGroup'))
    
    observeEvent(input[[remove_id]], {
      
      removeUI(selector = paste0('#', remove_group))
      rv$rmvd = c(rv$rmvd, str_extract(remove_id, '\\d+$'))
      
    })
  })
  
  observe({
    
    diff = rv$ct - length(rv$rmvd)
    
    delay(1000, toggleState(selector = 'div.rmvBttn', condition = diff > 1)) #not working 
    
    # Other selectors I have tried that don't work:
    # delay(1000, toggleState(selector = paste0('#', ns('placeholder'), 'button'), condition = diff > 1))
    # delay(1000, toggleState(selector = 'button[id *= "remove"]', condition = diff > 1))
    
    # Using the id works:
    # delay(1000, toggleState(id = 'remove1', condition = diff > 1)) #this works
    
  })
}

# main UI -----------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-split-layout > div { overflow: visible; }'))),
  
  modUI('mod')
  
)

# main server -------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  callModule(modServer, 'mod')
  
}

# Run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Since the user can insert any number of inputs and remove them individually at random, the full ID of the last remaining remove button in the DOM is unknown so I am using the `selector` argument of `toggleState` instead of the `id` argument. I have tried variations of the following `selectors`, none of which appear to be working:

`button[id *= "remove"]`

`paste0('#', ns('placeholder'), 'button')`

`div.rmvBttn`

What's confusing me is that they seem to work just fine in the non-modularised verion of the app (see below):

```js
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# UI -----------------------------------------------------------------


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-split-layout > div { overflow: visible; }'))),
  
  tagList(
    actionButton('add', 'Add'),
    fluidRow(div(id = 'placeholder'))
  )
  
)


# server -------------------------------------------------------------


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv = reactiveValues(ct = 0, rmvd = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    
    rv$ct = rv$ct + 1
    
    Id = function(id) paste0(id, rv$ct)
    
    insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#placeholder'),
      ui = div(
        id = Id('inputGroup'),
        splitLayout(
          cellWidths = '10%',
          h4(Id('State ')),
          selectInput(Id('state'), 'State:', state.abb),
          div(
            class = 'rmvBttn',
            actionButton(Id('remove'), 'Remove'))
        )
        
      )
    )
    
    remove_id = Id('remove')
    remove_group = Id('inputGroup')
    
    
    observeEvent(input[[remove_id]], {
      
      removeUI(selector = paste0('#', remove_group))
      rv$rmvd = c(rv$rmvd, str_extract(remove_id, '\\d+$'))
      
    })
  })
  
  observe({
    
    diff = rv$ct - length(rv$rmvd)
    
    # delay(1000, toggleState(selector = 'div.rmvBttn', condition = diff > 1)) 
    # delay(1000, toggleState(selector = '#placeholder button', condition = diff > 1))
    delay(1000, toggleState(selector = 'button[id *= "remove"]', condition = diff > 1))
    
    
  })
  
}

# Run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As a check, providing the full ID works in both the modularised and non-modularised versions, e.g. `toggleState(id = 'remove2', condition = diff > 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a class to the buttons:

```
actionButton(Id(ns('remove')), 'Remove', class = 'rmvBttn')
```

(not to the div containing the button).

It's very strange that

```
toggleState(selector = '.rmvBttn', condition = diff > 1)
```

does not work. Instead of that, you can do:

```
if(diff <= 1){
  delay(1000, runjs("$('.rmvBttn').attr('disabled', true)"))
}else{
  delay(1000, runjs("$('.rmvBttn').attr('disabled', false)"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Stéphane, your solution works perfectly. I had missed the `...` in the `actionButton` documentation so didn't realise that I could pass a class to it directly.

Comment: When You use `selector` argument inside a module the id argument is automatically added to the underlying object. The id is your module's namespace generated with the NS function. According to documentation, if the id is provided, the selector is ignored. That's why it's not working. For me, it's an issue/bug. The mechanism works well when you're operating on ids, then You don't need to prefix ids with the namespace. But if You want to use selectors it won't work :(